# Xamarin.forms UITest md5 not found error

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Im new to Xamarin.forms development and am trying to write some UI tests.

I am on mac and have followed [this guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/uitest-and-test-cloud/) and the tests have run fine on iOS. However, for the Android tests the emulator doesn't even start and gives the following output:

> SetUp : System.Exception : Failed to execute: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell md5 /data/app/com.mysite.my_app-1/base.apk - exit code: 127
>   /system/bin/sh: md5: not found

I find this quite odd seeing as I don't get any errors relating to md5 when I run my Android emulator for debugging purposes.

Anyone have any ideas of what needs to be done to get these Android tests running?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved it. Just had to update Xamarin.UITest to the latest (but not NUnit seeing as its Xamarin.UITest is not compatible with NUnit 3 and above)